# Android draw path with animation

Tags: android, animation, path

I would like create this effect, [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NxG3BE9QCg) draw path with animation. I have path but i dont know how can i animate this path, so that it drew current path with time. Animation like USA draw path map. How works object animator in android?

Can you help me?

Comment: the link you posted has another link to author's blog explaining  how it works

Comment: dont help me this tut, doesn't work

Comment: man,  this guy gave you the **complete source code** to the app and you are saing "doesn't work"?

Comment: Try download source code, compile and install apk. This code is to hard, and appp doesn't work

Comment: if it's too hard to analyze the code, the author also explained the main classes that make the trick,  what's unclear?